# How can I import a React component into another component?

Tags: reactjs

In React I'm trying to import and render one component named Followed into another component named Carousel2, but it's an error:

> Can't resolve './Followed/Followed' in 'C:\Dev\React_Nft_Landing\nft_landing\src\components\Carousel2'

Both components are placed in ./components folder, and I can't resolve this simple I think problem.

Below is Carousel2.jsx component code

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
        
import './carousel2.scss';                  

import Followed from './Followed/Followed';


const Carousel2 = () => {

  return (

    <div class="carousel_container">

        <h2 className="carousel_title"> Top List Creator</h2>

        <div className="carousel_switch">
            <a href="#"><button       className="btn1">Popular</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button className="btn2">Following</button></a>
        </div>
       
<> 
  < Followed />
</>

        </div>
  )
}

export default Carousel2
```

Comment: Is that where the `Followed` component is? In the `Carousel2` directory, in a folder named `Followed` containing a file also named `Followed.js`?

Comment: *"Both components are placed in ./components folder"* - Then why does your path include a folder called `Followed`?

Comment: Add your directory structure to your question. The current state of the question is contradictory

Answer (score 0):

As one comment suggested:
If both components are placed in ./components folder then you don't need to include the folder called Followed.

- import Followed from './Followed/Followed';

It should be:

- import Followed from './Followed

But since we can't see your project structure, I'm gonna give you some examples of how to import components given different paths.

Example 1:

- components/
- - Carousel2.js
- - Followed.js
- Inside Carousel2.js: import Followed from './Followed'

Example 2:

- components/
- - Carousel2/Carousel2.js
- - Followed/Followed.js
- Inside Carousel2.js: import Followed from '../Followed/Followed'

Example 3:

- components/
- - Carousel2/Carousel2.js
- - Carousel2/index.js exporting Carousel2.js as default.
- - Followed/Followed.js
- - Followed/index.js exporting Followed.js as default.
- Inside Carousel2.js: import Followed from '../Followed'